# Joining to tables while linking with a crosswalk table

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a query to de identify one of my tables. To make distinct ids for people, I used name, age and sex.  However in my main table, the data has been collected for years and the sex code changed from 1 meaning male and 2 meaning female to M meaning male and F meaning female. To make this uniform in my distinct individuals table I used a crosswalk table to convert the sexcode into to the correct format before placing it into the distinct patients table.

I am now trying to write the query to match the distinct patient ids to their correct the rows from the main. table. The issue is that now the sexcode for some has been changed.  I know I could use an update statement on my main table and changes all of the 1 and 2 to the m and f.  However, I was wondering if there was a way to match the old to the new sexcodes so I would not have to make the update.  I did  not know if there was a way to join the main and distinct ids tables in the query while using the sexcode table to convert the sexcodes again. Below are the example tables I am currently using.

This is my main table that I want to de identify

```
----------------------------  
| Name | age | sex |  Toy  |
---------------------------- 
| Stacy| 30  | 1   | Bat   |
| Sue  | 21  | 2   | Ball  |
| Jim  | 25  | 1   | Ball  |
| Stacy| 30  | M   | Ball  |
| Sue  | 21  | F   | glove |
| Stacy| 18  | F   | glove |
----------------------------
```

Sex code crosswalk table

```
-------------------  
| SexOld | SexNew |  
-------------------  
|  M     |   M    | 
|  F     |   F    | 
|  1     |   M    |  
|  2     |   F    |  
-------------------
```

This is the table I used to to populate IDs for people I found to be distinct in my main table

```
--------------------------  
| ID | Name | age |  sex |  
--------------------------  
|  1 | Stacy| 30  |  M   |  
|  2 | Jim  | 25  |  M   |  
|  3 | Stacy| 18  |  F   |   
|  4 | Sue  | 21  |  F   |  
--------------------------
```

This what I want my de identified table to look like

```
--------------- 
| ID  |  Toy  |
---------------
| 1   | Bat   |
| 4   | Ball  |
| 2   | Ball  |
| 1   | Ball  |
| 4   | glove |
| 3   | glove |
---------------
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have got so far?

Comment: Also specify what RDBMS you're using.

Comment: while yes you can cross walk, why on earth would you not want to fix the data? Do you want to make it difficult to query forever?

Comment: I agree with @HLGEM. Just fix the data so you can have easier queries going forward, especially if it's just for this column. You'd just write an update statement to change the values, and then you'd be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.ID, a.Toy
from maintable a
left join sexcodecrosswalk b on b.sexold = a.sex
left join peopleids c on c.Name = a.Name and c.age = a.age and c.Sex = b.sexNew
```

Here's a demonstration that this works:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a2d26/1